# Should I use CliWrap or Process Class? (asynchronous programming or not)

Tags: c#, asynchronous, parallel-processing, process, snmp

I'm writing a program for snmp monitoring. I need to make multiple snmprequests to a wlan controller. Afterwards I need to parse the output and extract information.
This information will be written into a database, to be displayed on a website.

I'm wondering what would be faster and easier to work with, CliWrap or Process Class?

Right now I'm working with CliWrap package and made a Task for every snmprequest. It's working, but it seems a little slow. I expected it to be fast, because I thought with CliWrap I can execute multiple snmprequests concurrently?

Here's my code:

```
namespace WlcInformation { 
class Program {
static async Task Main(string[] args) {
  IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
  .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()) 
  .AddJsonFile("snmpcommands.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true) 
  .Build();

   var appConfig = configuration.GetSection("Commands").Get<AppConfig>();

   //create a list of tasks vor each snmp request
   List<Task<string>> snmptasks = new List<Task<string>>();

   CliWrapSnmpCommandExecutor executor = new CliWrapSnmpCommandExecutor();

   string snmpwalkCommand = $"{appConfig.SnmpWalkExe}";

   foreach (var bssidOid in appConfig.BssidOids) {
     foreach (var controller in appConfig.AllControllers) {
       string arguments = $"{bssidOid.Options} {appConfig.Options} {controller.ReadCommunity}       {controller.ControllerIp} {bssidOid.Oid}";
       snmptasks.Add(ExecuteSnmpCommandAsync(snmpwalkCommand, arguments, executor));
      }
    }

   await Task.WhenAll(snmptasks); //wait for all tasks to finish

   foreach (var task in snmptasks) {
     string output = await task;
     Console.WriteLine(output);
   }

}
    
  public static async Task<string> ExecuteSnmpCommandAsync(string snmpwalkCommand, string arguments,     CliWrapSnmpCommandExecutor executor) {
    try {   Console.WriteLine($"Ausführung von MyAsyncMethod mit: {snmpwalkCommand} {arguments}");
            string output = await executor.CliWrapExecuteCommand(snmpwalkCommand, arguments);
            return output;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Console.WriteLine($"Fehler in Task: {ex.Message}");
        return string.Empty;
      }
   }
}

class CliWrapSnmpCommandExecutor {
        public async Task<string> CliWrapExecuteCommand(string snmpwalkCommand, string arguments) {
             var result = await Cli.Wrap(snmpwalkCommand)
            .WithArguments($"{arguments}")
            .ExecuteBufferedAsync();
            var standardoutput = result.StandardOutput;
            return string.Join(Environment.NewLine, standardoutput);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: _"but it seems a little slow"_ - and you think the cli-interfacing is your bottleneck? Have your tried to benchmark(dotnet) _one_ command done in CliWrapper against the same in Process?

Comment: The execution time for a single command is very similar (CliWrap: 6149 ms, Process: 6269 ms), the execution time for my program (10 commands) with CliWrap is 29795 ms, so I guess my program is faster than I thought? Wish it was way faster though, but thank you.

Comment: The question would be: _Can_ it be faster? That is: We established that it doesn't really matter if CliWrapper or Process class is in use. Second: You _feel_ like the overall execution time could be faster. Now, what do you execute through CliWrapper? Coud _that_ be made faster? Would it be faster to not execute out-of-process but in-process? ... Is it possible and reasonable to make some calls concurrent?

Comment: Libraries like #SNMP (I am the main contributor) were created to free people from calling command line executable and parsing console output.